# Retrieve Past 7 days Order History from Order Table

Tags: mysql

Given Order Table with Columns **Customer_Id, Order_Date, Quantity**. How to generate another column that has Sum of Quantity for past seven days excluding the current order date.

Input:

```
CUSTOMER_ID ORDER_DATE  QUANTITY
          1 2019-05-01  1
          1 2019-05-02  1
          2 2019-05-02  1
          2 2019-05-03  1
          2 2019-05-04  1
          1 2019-05-05  1
          2 2019-05-05  1
          1 2019-05-06  1
          2 2019-05-06  1
          1 2019-05-07  1
          2 2019-05-07  1
          1 2019-05-08  1
          2 2019-05-08  1
          1 2019-05-09  1
          1 2019-05-10  1
          1 2019-05-11  1
          2 2019-05-11  1
          2 2019-05-12  1
          2 2019-05-13  1
          2 2019-05-14  1
          2 2019-05-15  1
          1 2019-05-16  1
```

Output:

```
CUSTOMER_ID ORDER_DATE  QUANTITY    ORDER_HISTORY
         1  2019-05-01  1           0
         1  2019-05-02  1           1
         2  2019-05-02  1           0
         2  2019-05-03  1           1
         2  2019-05-04  1           2
         1  2019-05-05  1           2
         2  2019-05-05  1           3
         1  2019-05-06  1           3
         2  2019-05-06  1           4
         1  2019-05-07  1           4
         2  2019-05-07  1           5
         1  2019-05-08  1           4
         2  2019-05-08  1           6
         1  2019-05-09  1           4
         1  2019-05-10  1           5
         1  2019-05-11  1           6
         2  2019-05-11  1           4
         2  2019-05-12  1           4
         2  2019-05-13  1           4
         2  2019-05-14  1           4
         2  2019-05-15  1           4
         1  2019-05-16  1           2
```

So far, I tried using `DATE_SUB(ORDER_DATE, INTERVAL 6 DAY)` without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a correlated subquery to find the 7 day rolling sums:

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    ORDER_DATE,
    QUANTITY,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.QUANTITY) FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t1.CUSTOMER_ID = t2.CUSTOMER_ID AND
           t2.ORDER_DATE >= DATE_SUB(t1.ORDER_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
           t2.ORDER_DATE < t1.ORDER_DATE) AS ORDER_HISTORY
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY ORDER_DATE;
```

Comment: @Strawberry I have reverted the question to the original version, which is what my answer addresses.

Comment: My bad!! I made changes to the table and lost the edits